# socket.connect() freezes windows

Tags: c#, sockets

I have code which tries to establish connection every 3 seconds using TCP and a blocking socket. Whenever it tries to establish the connection with socket.connect(), all my windows applications freeze for a moment, I can't even type in notepad. I have tested it on 2 PCs with same result. The codes resides in a timer event.

How do I avoid freezing without using asynchronous methods?

Code:

```
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ip, mainPort);

// Create a TCP/IP  socket.
commandReceiverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
commandReceiverSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, 0);
commandReceiverSocket.Blocking = true;
commandReceiverSocket.Connect(remoteEP);
```

Comment: If you can't type in external applications somthing else is going on. Most likely that kind of behavior is seen when you are using 100% of the CPU in your app. What is your CPU usage percentage when your computer acts like this?

Comment: No, CPU usage stays under 5%.

Comment: Now I moved the code out of the timer event inside a while loop of the form load event and it only freezes once for 1-2 seconds, on startup.

Comment: 'all my windows applications freeze for a moment, I can't even type in notepad' - that is VERY strange.  It sounds like a bad driver to me:(

Comment: I also tried moving the connection code to a different thread, the freezing is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to establish a connection from within a UI thread in any language can cause this. It is not healthy at all to call this from within a loop or a timer in the form of you application.

Try to run everything related to the connection in a different thread and don't use the UI thread.